# take images from a seperate folder in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an **images array** having three jpg's. I'm setting the background image of class **pic** from images array.

My problem is that I have put the images in **images folder** having URL `images/`.  i want to add `images/` to line

```
document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+images[index]+')';
```

How to do this?

```js
var images = ['bus.jpg','car.jpg','scooter.jpg' ];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+images[index]+')';
}

function changeImage() {
index++;
if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ images[index] + ')';
}
```

```html
<div class="pic" id="content" >
```

Comment: What's the full path of the images directory? Like `http://example.com/images/bus.jpg`?

Comment: `document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/'+ images[index] + ')';`

Comment: @craig-van-tonder yes

Comment: @matejko219 that solved the problem thanks

Comment: Sure so the simpliest way to combine two strings is to concatenate them, it works like `alert('one string'+'otherstring')` ouputs `one stringotherstring`

Answer (score 4):

you can simply concat folder path.

```
var images = ['bus.jpg','car.jpg','scooter.jpg' ];
var index = 0;
var FolderPath="Images/";

function buildImage() {
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+FolderPath+images[index]+')';
}

function changeImage() {
index++;
if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
    document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+FolderPath+ images[index] + ')';
}
```

Comment: Might also be able to use the string template syntax like: `\`url(${FolderPath}${images[index]})\``

Comment: i was not knowing it, thanks @CraigvanTonder for sharing knowledge it will be helpful :)

Comment: Useful to note that it came in ES2015 so would not be compatible with all web browsers, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

If you are very sure about the the path, you can use it as below.

```
document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ FolderPath + images[index] + ')';
```